# Tesseract max recognition time in android

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two, text-recognition

I have a problem with tesseract recognition time in android, it's taking too much time to recognize text. In ios it has a function to give tesseract max recognition time like `tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0`.
Is there any way to give tesseract maximum recognition time in android like ios?(I'm using tess two library https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you would be welcome to propose a pull request to implement it!

You may be able to use the [`stop`](https://rmtheis.github.io/tess-two/javadoc/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.html#stop()) method as an alternative.